# Can't connect to postgres db with jdbc

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, jdbc, psql

*Note: I'm calling the security service the problem service here, but I doubt I can connect to the DB with any service- security is just the first one that has to do it.*

I'm trying to modify a java application to use postgres instead of oracle, I'm getting connection issues, and my logs are not helpful.

The database is on a remote server, but it is being accessed successfully by other applications. I can connect with the postgres client without issue.

Any ideas where I should look?

The errors:

from the service I'm calling:

```
2020-08-11 14:47:37 INFO  AuthenticationService:32 - Rest Services - starting authentication...
2020-08-11 14:47:38 ERROR AuthenticationService:119 - GetUserInfo: trying to connect to the Rest Serrvice, attempt 1, HTTP Error Code: 500
2020-08-11 14:47:38 ERROR AuthenticationService:120 - Response message: Internal Server Error
2020-08-11 14:47:38 ERROR AuthenticationService:146 - Problem getting User Info: Problem getting User Info 500, message: Internal Server Error
2020-08-11 14:47:38 ERROR AuthenticationService:62 - Problem getting User Info: Problem getting User Info 500, message: Internal Server Error
```

From the underlying problem service:

```
2020-08-11 14:47:38 INFO  SecurityService:67 - Rest Services - getUserInfo
2020-08-11 14:47:38 INFO  SecurityService:87 - Getting User Info from DB...
2020-08-11 14:47:38 ERROR SecurityService:110 - Couldn't establish connection to Database
```

My context.xml for problem service (resource section is identical in both services):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context path="/PhoenixSecurity" docBase="PhoenixSecurity"
   crossContext="true" reloadable="true" debug="1">

<Resource name="jdbc/CtsRest" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://CORRECT-IP:5432/phoenix"
          username="validUser" password="validPassword" maxActive="100" maxIdle="100" maxWait="-1"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: Can the JVM reach port 5432?

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't be able to, but I also am not sure of how to easily check that

Comment: The logging suggest that your own code logs _"Couldn't establish connection to Database"_, I'd recommend that you also log the actual exception stacktrace, so you know what is wrong.

Comment: @flammino write a small Jsp page that manually loads the driver and makes a connection, and a small query you know to return data.

Answer (score 0):

In troubleshooting these sorts of problems check the following in order:

1. Can you connect to PostgreSQL from another machine on the LAN?  If not, it may not be listening on the address?
2. Can you connect locally?  Is it even running?

Now in the case where the second succeeds and the first fails, here are things to check in order:

1. `listen_address` in postgresql.conf
2. firewall rules
3. Anything in between that might interfere with the network connections.

*Sometimes when you pass localhost in the jdbc url this will be mapped to ipv6 address. Try specifying the the ip4 address explicitly.

Comment: I am using an IP- the DB is not running on the localhost. Connecting to the db from the shell using psql -h [correct-ip] -U username -d phoenix does work from the same machine I'm running tomcat on

Comment: Also you need to add rule to pg_hba.conf file that allow remote connection. host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my issue was assuming that the jdbc driver for postgres could create a connection the same way as the one for oracle. It can't. Lesson learned.

Comment: Can you be more precise? The way a connection is created with JDBC is always the same. You provide the URL, username and password and the driver does the rest. There shouldn't be any difference in the code for different drivers